# Check which module imported

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am running an app on Google app engine that uses `urlfetch` in production, but uses `requests` locally. For example:

```
try:
    import urlfetch
except:
    import requests
```

The two modules act differently, so it's not as easy as just aliasing it, like `json` vs `simplejson`. How would I tell which module I have imported? For example, something like:

```
if 'urlfetch' loaded:
    urlfetch(method='post', url='url', ...)
else:
    requests.post(url)
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, `urlfetch` works locally so what's your motivation?

Comment: You have to run it from within Google's 'test environment' though, correct? Locally, I'm just developing with no GAE-dependencies for now.

Comment: Why not use requests in all cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sys.modules` to see which modules have been imported. For example:

```
>>> import sys; reload(sys)
>>> 'urlfetch' in sys.modules
True
```